# What's wrong with my custom hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, single-page-application

Hi Stack Overflow Community!

I am learning react and now I am practicing custom hooks. I get the example data from here:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

I've got two components.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import useComments from "./hooks/useComments"

const App = () => {

  const Comments = useComments();

  const renderedItems = Comments.map((comment) => {
    return <li key={comment.id}>{comment.title}</li>;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Comments</h1>
     <ul>{renderedItems}</ul> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

useComments.js

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const useComments = () => {

    const [Comments, setComments] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
            "mode": "cors",
            "credentials": "omit"
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => setComments(data))
    }, []);


    return [Comments];
};

export default useComments;
```

My output looks like this and i don't know why. There are no warnings or errors.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line makes `Comments` be an array:

```
const [Comments, setComments] = useState([]);
```

...and then you're wrapping it in an additional array:

```
return [Comments];
```

But when you use it, you're treating it as a single dimensional array.

```
const Comments = useComments();

const renderedItems = Comments.map...
```

So you'll just need to line those two up. If you want two levels of array-ness (perhaps because you plan to add more to your hook, so that it's returning more things than just `Comments`), then the component will need to remove one of them. This can be done with destructuring, as in:

```
const [Comments] = useComments();
```

Alternatively, if you don't need that complexity, you can change your hook to not add the extra array, and return this:

```
return Comments;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And what happens if I want to return two objects? it will be this-> return [comments, otherReturnObject]; ?

Comment: Then when you use the hook, do: `const [Comments, otherObject] = useComments()`